# Customer Technical Support or Technical Customer Support?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I am part of a customer support team.
When answering a new email request from a customer I start my reply with an introduction:

> Hi, *John Doe* here from the **[What-goes-here?]** team at *Such-and-Such-copmany-name*, ...

My question is what would be correct (instead of the 'What-goes-here?' above)

> Customer Technical Support

or

> Technical Customer Support

Can't seem to make up my mind, what works better / sounds correct.

**Update**: The reason I am in this dilemma is because I want to distinguish the type of 'Technical Support'.

We support only paying customers, there is also Professional Services (payed by the hour doing customization and large deployment), and Sales level support which isn't provided by the field sales teams.

There are also sales/lead support which answer trial software users.

I would like the name to distinguish this.

Comment: *Technical* modifies *support,* not *customer:* it's 'Customer Technical Support.' Don't try to "make up the mind," follow the established terminology. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_support http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_support

Comment: I think his intent with the second version is _Technical (Customer Support)_ -- the type of customer support they provide is technical, rather than business. But @Kris is correct that this is not the common term.

Comment: I would just go with _"Technical Support"_. When you say something like- _"Hi, this is John, from the technical support team"_, it also does imply that you work in customer support.

Comment: I believe I'll stick with Customer Technical Support for now. @Barmar, you are absolutely correct, that's the source of the dilemma, I've updated the question to explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Customer technical support" is a common term that means "technical support for customers." This distinguishes it from internal technical support for the business.

"Technical customer support" is a far less common term, which makes me have to think for a second about its meaning. I doubt that I'm going to take the time to think it over as you answer the phone. Instead, it will probably slip right past, and you won't have gained anything from having used it.

It's probably more to the point to confirm that the caller has reached technical support, and then redirect the caller if they'd be better served by some other department. I doubt that any misdirected caller is going to have their confusion cleared up merely by hearing the word "customer" in either of those terms.

If you're dead set on going with one or the other of those terms, however, I suggest you search the internet using "technical customer service." The results will be illuminating. It's probably not the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Quite certainly, there are business parts of a company (such as inquiring about quarterly reports or press releases), but considering you're asking about "customer technical or technical customer", it's fair to assume you're talking about the technical part of the business

When you work as the technical support, most definitely you're supporting a customer, not something else (definitely not a supervillain hell bent on destroying the world, right?), so you can omit the Customer there and use *Technical Support* alone

Now, when you want to distinguish the different tiers of support, just put the modifier in front of it, like *Professional Technical Support* although that implies that any support other than that one is not professional.

Maybe you can try *Technical Support for Professional Services*, assuming you're talking about providing support to customers in Professional tier, and not about providing support to customers that want to upgrade to Professional tier (that'd be *Professional Services Support*)